# Vertical-align: middle - img in div (different size picture)

Tags: html, css, image, vertical-alignment

I was not successful CSS. Should be in the center of the picture (different size) in the `div`. See an example:

[image: image example]

And examples of html and css - http://jsfiddle.net/KJXUt/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
  <a href="#" class="pic">
    <img src="http://pics.posternazakaz.ru/pnz/product/small_x2/97/61/ccc0980cde08f9032cd665f7104aca10.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="130" />
  </a>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <a href="#" class="pic">
    <img src="http://www.22.ru/ow_userfiles/plugins/photo/photo_preview_137.jpg" alt="" width="140" height="140" />
  </a>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background: #D6E8FF;
}
.box {
    border: #555 1px solid;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table-cell;          /* <-- problem */
    vertical-align: middle;       /* <-- problem */
}
img {
    max-width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}
```

​

How to correct style? Help, please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term to make a picture smaller without re-sizing it is called "cropping", to directly achieve your answer, a different css property: `background` will be used. And the div's will be removed. [@Heliio's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066761/vertical-align-middle-img-in-div-different-size-picture/13069894#13069894) is great if you need `<div>` tags.

A code sample is as following
HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="pic pic1">
&nbsp;
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.pic {
    display:inline-block;
    border: #555 1px solid;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.pic1{
 background: transparent url(http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/62256112.jpg) -20px -200px no-repeat;
}
```

Note that the css has some negative values, these are extremely tedious to modify, but it's really just `-((imagewidth-100)/2)  x  -((imageheight-100)/2)`

http://jsfiddle.net/KJXUt/9/

Comment: Hello, extramaster. Yesterday, I had an idea that another plan. That's how I thought the same about this. Thanks in advance for the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you use display: table-cell; it's forcing to fixed size to the cells. Maybe it's not a good solution.

I dont understand, if want really it, but:

```
body {
    background: #D6E8FF;
}
.box {
    border: #555 1px solid;
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/KJXUt/1/

Or, if prefer: http://jsfiddle.net/KJXUt/3/

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple technique to center the image vertically in `.box`

http://codepen.io/AntonNiklasson/pen/pkaov

To add more boxes next to eachother, add `float: left` to `.box`